# Unicode Problem

Tags: language

I am just in the test phase to launch our [News Portal](http://udaipurtimes.com/hindi) in Hindi Language.

For writing the posts in hindi, I've installed Indic IME plugin which translates my english word to hindi format (like google transliterate does). Plus, I also use Google transliterate to write posts and then paste it in post box and publish it.

The problem is - To 75% of the users the Hindi that is being displayed on site is same as I want, but on rest it changes to either other words or square boxes.

I also commented
//define(‘DB_CHARSET’, ‘utf8′);
//define(‘DB_COLLATE’, ”);
in wp-config as suggested on some site. But no avail.

The official launch is being postponed of this reason only. Please revert back if you have any solution.

Any clue, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

If these are really square boxes and not question marks (or the Unicode replacement character for invalid byte sequences), then the browser doesn’t find a font to display the characters. Embed a web font with all the characters needed.

Comment: I did as you suggested and included Arial Unicode MS to the font it should use, but the problem is still there.

Here is the screenshot [http://i.imgur.com/AtE08.jpg] of the problem am facing, maybe this could help in putting my question in right way.

Please revert back if you have any solution for this, thanks a ton.

Comment: Please do not accept my answer if it doesn’t solve your problem. I cannot see squares on the screen shot?

Comment: in the screenshot squares are not there, yes. But as you can see, the word is something else of what it needs to be. Its like sometimes this 'mismatched-word' problem occurs and sometimes 'square-problem'. Though, I think 'mismatched-word' problem is the main.

Comment: the screenshot that I took was from two different computers in my same office. And I checked that, both have Arial Unicode MS installed.

Now, there is also one site who displays Hindi language News [www.bbc.co.uk/hindi] (run by bbc) and the content is always right on every computer. i checked. So why am not able to get it. I digged deep using fiebug but can't see the difference of what they are doing to achieve the uniformity of their fonts shown to every user.